# Random generation of text and play as an audio JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, audio

I have text randomly generated. I wanted that text to be play as an audio in the JSP Page.

Can anybody suggest some ideas?.

Comment: Please share your code first.

Comment: you need a plugin to read your text and synthesize some voice to create an audio file or stream for you.

Comment: I din't get any code. That's why I asked ideas.

Comment: http://osama-oransa.blogspot.ru/2012/06/text-to-speech-in-jsp-page-or-html.html